Unable to upgrade 23.10 to 24.04 "No new release found"
I am unable to upgrade 23.10 to 24.04 using do-release-upgrade or the Software Updater app, receiving the message "No new release found".
Here's what I'm doing:
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found.

The file /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades is set to Prompt=normal. If I use Prompt=lts I get a slightly different message:
sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS development release
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.


Upgrades to 24.04 are not currently available due to problems... though you may now have additional problems due to EOL status of your release (leaving it too long)   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades
